# ActionBarSherlock with custom RelativeLayout does not show title text

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

The ActionBar does not show title when using relative layout.
And when I not use the RelativeLayout, the items are not aligned to right.
Please don't tell me to use menu items as the solution. It must be custom.

Here is how I set it:

```
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayOptions(
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP |
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM |
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME |
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE |
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);

    bar.setTitle(title);
    bar.setCustomView(actionBar);
    this.setTitle(title);
```

This is when the align is good, but title is not shown

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/acion_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_label_add"
            style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_prev"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_label_prev"
            style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_label_next"
            style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Screenshot](http://i48.tinypic.com/96cg9y.png)

And here comes the layout where the title is shown, but the items are aligned to left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/acion_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_label_add"
        style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/action_prev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_label_prev"
        style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/action_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_label_next"
        style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[Screenshot](http://i46.tinypic.com/2gy0yep.png)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same problem and found this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/He6gst4nvR0

This worked for me:

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

code:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
...
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(segmentView, lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround by adding TextView with titleTextStyle to the layout.
If any of you have a better answer i'm looking forward to see it.

My workaround:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/player_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttons_holder"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Title"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/acion_add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_label_add"
            style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_prev"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_label_prev"
            style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_label_next"
            style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have done the same thing. Unfortunatly this doesn't work properly in RTL devices.