# Android action bar items on the left side of the action bar

Tags: java, android

I am required to create an action bar that has its items split: four of them on the right side and four on the left (it's a tablet-only application). In portrait mode they shouldn't be split. Is it possible to implement without using a custom view for the left side of the action bar, as it seems inconsistent?

Note that I want to know how to do it with the **default action items**, not with the custom ones in a custom view, and that **I don't have any influence on the UI decisions**, so please do not suggest to change the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ActionBar items are aligned to the right. It is not possible without custom view.
But you can use actionViewStyle for buttons to make them styled as menu items.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13143180/1366471

Comment: This would do just fine, but "?attr/actionButtonStyle" causes an error on build (it can't find the style). I tried to change it to "android:actionButtonStyle", but it frankly doesn't change anything. How do I use that correctly?

Comment: You should reference ActionBarSherlock project. This constant is from ActionBarSherlock.