# How to center title in ActionBarSherlock with menu items?

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

In order to center the title in my topbar, I set up custom view for ActionBarSherlock like this:

```
ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

ab.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
ab.setCustomView(R.layout.topbar);
```

My custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    >
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/sideMenuButton"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_menu"
        />
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And well, this works - until it shows menu buttons (buttons on the right).

They are inflated:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    //...
}
```

Items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_share"
        android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_foo"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/foo"
        android:visible="false"/>

//...
</menu>
```

How can I get the whole layout of the topbar - such that if I say "center", it really centers in all the available width? I don't have problems with possible overlapping, since the centered logo and the menu items are images with fixed size.

I could also measuere the width of the screen and set left margin dynamically, but I hope there's a better solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You are deviating from the standard and thus unnecessarily confusing users - especially if your are sticking to the rest of the ActionBar pattern like your actionbar items (menu items).

Comment: Because my client wants the title/logo in the center, not at the left. It's how design was made, and the iOS app also has it like that - button on the left for side menu, title in the center, other button at the right.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. iOS and Android are totally different systems. You should educate your client, because otherwise the client will get bad app ratings.

Comment: Well, surely I will tell the client about Android visual/usability guidelines, but still I don't see a practical reason why iOS the title can be centered and in Android can't (or shouldn't).

Comment: Possible is a lot - though not everything is wise. I think one should stick to what users expect - and on Android that is a left-aligned title. If the client still insists, by all means do as he wishes. After all, you have to pay your bills. I just think it's wise to inform the client that users do not like deviations from the platform style. He wouldn't want a left-centered title on iOS as well - for the very same reason.

Comment: Well, yes, I think that the client may agree. Now that I think I could just add the right button in the custom view and disable the menu options completly - but if the users are really expecting the logo on the left side, this should be enough argument for the client.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13634570/1318946