# Add images to android Action bar that aren't action items

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-manifest

I want to add 2 little icons that will sometimes appear on the action bar. These icons won't be clickable though so I don't want to add them as an action item. What ways can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom layout for your action bar and attached it like so

```
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.MY_CUSTOM_LAYOUT, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

Comment: Any difference if I declare my inflator like this?      LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();

Comment: That should be fine as well

Answer (score 1):

You can do 2 things, and be careful as they result in different layouts:

1) Passing the layout id:

```
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.MY_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
```

2) Passing a View:

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.MY_CUSTOM_LAYOUT, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

With option 1, my custom layout will behave like MATCH_PARENT, with option 2 it will behave like WRAP_CONTENT. I don't know the reason :S

hope it helps.

Comment: My problem was that sherlock action bar is using itws own LayoutParams object...follow the link to get the solution to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/13634570/751180